# Why EventListener remove function doesnt work with "querySelectorAll"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a long question about that before but I thnk people dont wanna waste time to read all code.. so I make simpler code to understand my question.. I reasearch that question in here too but couldnt find a solution...

question is easy : addeventlistener works but why removeeventlistener doesnt work...

Thanks.

```js
function addHandler() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bbb');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', whatever = function() {
      alert("");
    })
  })
}

function removeHandler() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bbb');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeEventListener('click', whatever)
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="kanban">

    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>

  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="removeHandler()">Remove</button>
  <button onclick="addHandler()">start</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: because you declare a function for each one and it will not equal the function you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of `whatever` every time you assign to it in your `forEach`, so only the last one is remembered. Later, when removing, that only succeeds in removing it from the last element.

You need to remember *each* function you create if you want to remove it later. For instance, you could keep them in a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) keyed by the element (example below). **That's just one option, though.** Often, you can avoid adding handlers to a bunch of elements by using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) instead.

Here's that `WeakMap` example:

```js
const handlers = new WeakMap();

function addHandler() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".bbb");
    elements.forEach(element => {
        const handler = function() {
          alert("");
        };
        element.addEventListener("click", handler);
        handlers.set(element, handler);
    });
}

function removeHandler() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".bbb");
    elements.forEach(element => {
        const handler = handlers.get(element);
        if (handler) {
            handlers.delete(element);
            element.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="kanban">

    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>

  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="removeHandler()">Remove</button>
  <button onclick="addHandler()">start</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's an example using event delegation, though, which is often cleaner:

```js
function handler(e) {
    // Starting from the innermost target of the event,
    // see if that element or any of its parents (in order)
    // matches the selector
    const element = e.target.closest(".bbb");
    // If we found one and it's inside the element we hooked
    // the event on, fire the handler code
    if (element && this.contains(element)) {
        alert(`Handled on "${element.textContent}"`);
    }
}

function addHandler() {
    // id="kanban" seems to be the nearest container of all
    // of the elements we want, so use that as the base for
    // delegation
    document.getElementById("kanban").addEventListener("click", handler);
}

function removeHandler() {
    document.getElementById("kanban").removeEventListener("click", handler);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<div id="kanban">

<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">BBBB </a>
<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">CCCC </a>
<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">DDDD </a>
<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">EEEE </a>
<a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">FFFF </a>

</div>
<br>
<button onclick="removeHandler()">Remove</button>
<button onclick="addHandler()">start</button>
```

---

Side note: If you look at the code in the answer above, you'll see `const` in various places where you didn't have anything. Your code was falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by assigning to undeclared identifiers. That's a bad idea. Instead, always declare your variables (and use strict mode — the default in standard modules — so that assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been).

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the `forEach` loop, `whatever` will contain the event listener that was added to the last `.bbb` element. If you try to use that when removing from other elements it won't work, because the listener functions will be different.

Rather than using a single variable, you can use an array of listeners.

```js
let bbb_listeners = [];

function addHandler() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bbb');
  elements.forEach((element, i) => {
    let listener = function() {
      alert(i);
    };
    bbb_listeners.push(listener);
    element.addEventListener('click', listener)
  })
}

function removeHandler() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bbb');
  elements.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.removeEventListener('click', bbb_listeners[i])
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="kanban">

    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>
    <a style="margin-left:20px" class="bbb">AAAA </a>

  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="removeHandler()">Remove</button>
  <button onclick="addHandler()">start</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks For solution.. But other solution is works better for me.. thanks anyway..

Comment: Yes, it's more general, as it will work if the list of elements changes dynamically.